# superfish menu indent issue

Tags: html, css, html-lists, superfish

I'm having a css issue where my menus with sub menus are indented differently that my menus without sub-menus. I've tried a number of solutions from google with no success.

For instance if you visit our site and hover over "drinkware" you'll see "liquor flasks" is more indented than the others. And under "home + bar" "man cave ideas" is not as indented as the others. http://www.homewetbar.com/

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

in `.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul` delete the padding-left line (currently `padding-left: 1em;`) and leave it like this:

```
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 1em;
    min-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work the padding-right and padding-left here keep the top navigation from collapsing onto itself (adds the spaces between the dividers) When I remove the padding-left the left side of the main nav runs into the divider and the spacing goes crazy.

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfect, are you sure? Basically that padding left is the indent you want to remove, because the indent for all other li elements is already defined

Comment: Hey Devin that worked. The issue was the aligned on the left was then different. So following your code change + adding padding-left 0.2em in the .sf-menu li { } class above that fixed it. Thanks!